# How do I get list of facebook friends using jquery autocomplete and graph api in javascript

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, search, facebook-friends

I'm making a facebook app (sort of), where people can answer questions  and rate their friends, I've gotten past the authentication and can get the user's fb name and profile picture, but after signing in, there's a big search field where you can search for friends and select them, then answer the questions, then post to their wall after the quiz.

I've checked all around and all answer either doesn't work or is outdated.

Any guideline or suggestion is appreciated.

I'm using the 2.8 version of the graph api

see pictures for clarification 
[sign in for the user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIbSs.jpg) and the search field showing a friend alraedy searched for --  [search field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/801Wf.jpg)

Comment: I don't believe you can get all someones FB friends anymore, only a list of their friends who have also enabled your app.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan oh wow, really, I tried the graph api console and it did show 1 friend and some other things [check here] (http://imgur.com/LZcpSiy)

Comment: That's just the number of friends that person has, not the details about those friends, is it not?

Comment: true.. so, what do you suggest, although I just want the name and picture, then post to the person's wall, and since the name is there already, I can get the picture using the id

Comment: Nothing to suggest I'm afraid. This is a restriction FB put in place. You can only get friends of the current user who have already enabled your app

Comment: hmm, like how a leader-board works right...